# Amazon Web Service - Route Traffic on ELB via SNI

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nfs, elastic-load-balancer

Sorry in advance if this doesn't make much sense. I'm fairly new to this, so bear with me please.

I'm trying to specify a domain to a specific folder depending on the domain name the user use (example.com or test123.com), through Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (Application load balancer to be specific).

My current setup is that all traffic from the internet goes to a Load Balancer (ELB), from there it round robin between 2 EC2 instances. Both instances are connected to an Amazon Network File System (EFS), as well as a Relational Database (RDS).
I can access the website(s) fine through the DNS of the load balancer (http://web-load-balancer-efs-16512354.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/example/)

What I want to do now set it up so that if someone put example.com as their url it will point to the Load Balancer and from there the server will use the correct folder as root (www.example.com document root would be http://web-load-balancer-efs-16512354.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/example/, but the URL will still be www.example.com).

I created a hosted zone on Route 53 to point the domain name to my load balancer, but currently my load balancer which leads to one of the ec2 instances. Currently the ec2 document root is /var/www/html/efs-mount/.
Is there a way for me to have multiple document root depending on the domain name?

I stumble on something about putting multiple TLS/SSL certificate on your listener and through SNI protocol it'll be able to find right place? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#https-listener-certificates. I'm not sure if this is what I need, or I'm completely off track.

If someone can point me to the right direction on how to do this that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed off track.

While ALB with multiple SSL certificates may be a part of your strategy, since it allows you to attach multiple ACM certificates to a single instance or group of instances, ALB does not re-write the paths of the incoming requests or determine how the instance resolves web paths into filesystem paths.

This is something configured in your web server itself.  Start by searching for something like "name based virtual hosting."  Each domain name will specify it's own "document root" in the web server configuration files.

Comment: would this be closer to what you mean? http://brianshim.com/webtricks/host-multiple-sites-amazon-ec2/

Comment: actually I found one that's a bit better and cleaner. https://nouveauframework.org/blog/vhosts-running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-aws-ec2-instance/
This works, but when I try using https:// it's not using the right certificate. it's using the default one. do I just add the port 443 to the <virtual host>?

Comment: The certificate is selected by the load balancer, not the instance.  Verify the settings, there.

Comment: hmm wierd, now the https:// www .example.com works, but https://example.com doesnt. When i create the certificate i put *.example.com. could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason.  In SSL certs, `*.` means exactly one token and exactly one dot.  `*.example.com` is valid for `foo.example.com` but not for `example.com` and also not for `foo.bar.example.com`.  If you are getting the cert from ACM, specify both `example.com` and `*.example.com` when creating the cert.

Comment: Also, note that on Stack Overflow, you can quote things with the backtick `\`` symbol in comments to prevent that look like URLs from becoming links, and to make sure small code snippets and literal strings get displayed correctly.

Comment: I think I might need to request another certificate. I dont think i can add `example.com` into the current certificate. Thanks for your help/tip!

Comment: Correct, you can't modify an existing certificate -- but you can request a single certificate with both the bare domain and the wildcard.